# Return URL to redirect list view which is visualforce page

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, force.com

i have 1 custom object `test_2__c` and i created tab of it.

i have overridden this tab with a visual force page (tab redirect).

```
<apex:page action="{!URLFOR($Action.Test_2__c.List,$ObjectType.Test_2__c)}"/>
```

and i have 1 list button called "New". it is a button URL.

```
{!URLFOR($Action.Test_2__c.New)}?returnURL={/apex/tabredirect}
```

so when i click on this button from list view it opens an edit page for inserting a new record (The standard salesforce edit page, i didn't override it).

Now I am facing an issue here, when i click on "cancel" button from edit page, it remains on that page, i want to redirect it to list view which i have overridden with the visual force page.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a cancelURL parameter to the URL?  For example, you can send the user to a new visualforce page on cancel with the following parameter

```
...&cancelURL=/apex/YourApexPageNameHere
```